# How to make such a schedule?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-chart

[image]

It is necessary that all lines had different colors

The lines can be a maximum of 10 pieces

help me please

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/stacked-bar (It was not possible to make different color lines in each category :( )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the colorField property (API: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.colorField)

```
var data = [
    {x: "Name 1", y: 16, valueColor: "#556270"},
    {x: "Name 2", y: 13, valueColor: "#4ECDC4"},
    {x: "Name 3", y: 15, valueColor: "#C7F464"},
    {x: "Name 4", y: 14, valueColor: "#FF6B6B"},
    {x: "Name 5", y: 16, valueColor: "#C44D58"},
];


$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: data,
    series: [{
        type: "bar",
        field: "y",
        categoryField: "x",
        colorField: "valueColor"                    
    }],
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/jBzgGZ)**

Comment: how to do that in Y it was possible to insert text? I have data text there (

Comment: @enot, both x and y are text? How do you know size of the bars?